# Perform some code before a segue after I push a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uistoryboardsegue

I have a button that goes to another view. I want to perform some code before the segue moves. The problem I am facing is the segue goes to the other page before the code has a chance to finish. So the values that are in the User default don't get changed before the view gets changed. 
My question is how can I get the code to run and after its done get the segue to fire?
Here is what I have so far:

```
 @IBAction func onLogoutClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    //clear all url chache 
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    //null out everything for logout
    email = ""
    password = ""
    self.loginInformation.setObject(self.email, forKey: "email")
    self.loginInformation.setObject(self.password, forKey: "password")
    self.loginInformation.synchronize()
    //self.view = LoginView
}
```

Comment: Remove the action from the button in IB and then create a segue between the UIViewController object and your next scene.  You can then use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your `@IBAction` function.  The other approach is to get rid of the `@IBAction` method and implement `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: @Paulw11 could you put this as an answer so I can give you credit for it. Thank you for your help and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options;

The first is to remove the action from the button in IB and then create a segue between the UIViewController object and your next scene;

```
@IBAction func onLogoutClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    //clear all url chache 
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    //null out everything for logout
    email = ""
    password = ""
    self.loginInformation.setObject(self.email, forKey: "email")
    self.loginInformation.setObject(self.password, forKey: "password")
    self.loginInformation.synchronize()

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue",sender: self)
}
```

or you can get rid of the @IBAction method and implement prepareForSegueWithIdentifier

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
   if segue.identifier == "logoutSegue"  {
        //clear all url chache 
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        //null out everything for logout
        email = ""
        password = ""
        self.loginInformation.setObject(self.email, forKey: "email")
        self.loginInformation.setObject(self.password, forKey: "password")
        self.loginInformation.synchronize()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller you can implement:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Segue identifier set in storyboard") {
        // Put your code here or call onLogoutClick(null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "Segue identifier set in storyboard") {
            // Put your code here
        }
    }
```